# Создание абстрактного объекта в виде массива

Tags: java

```
public class Program {
String programs [];
public Program(String[] programs) {
    this.programs = programs;

}
```

Создаю обьект  Program program1=new Program(не понимаю как записать сюда несколько строковых значений);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
Program program1 = new Program(new String[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program1 = new Program(new String[]{"Вася","Петя"});
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

В Java есть синтаксис проще предложеного:

```
public class Program {

    private String programs[];

    public Program(String ... programs) {
        this.programs = programs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program1 = new Program("Вася", "Петя");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Это проще пока не передаётся 5,6,7,8...∞  элементов))

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский простите, а что измениться в сравнении с этой конструкцией new String[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"}?

Comment: Ну например это можно вынести в отдельную переменную и манипулировать ей сколько угодно. Отфильтровать, отсортировать, перемешать и т.д. А потом только передать в конструктор (передать **лишь одну** переменную массива). А у вас только ручками хардкорно вбить (даже если это всё в переменных, всё равно - куча переменных. Это не удобно). Плюс этот массив можно получить, например, из БД, из API, из файла и т.д. И это будет удобно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский public Program(String ... programs)  эта конструкция способна принять как вызов типа new Program("Вася", "Петя"), так и new Program(new String[]{"Вася","Петя"}), так что выносите в отдельную переменную сколько угодно, никаких проблем нет